# Помогите разобраться c PyQt, пожалуйста

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Если запускать функцию `button_clicked()` напрямую из `__init__`, то в окне создастся лейбл, но если ту же функцию запустить с кнопки `(b1.clicked.connect)`- ничего не создаётся.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
import sys


class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()

        self.b1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.b1.setText("click me!")
        self.button_clicked()  # запускаем напрямую
        # self.b1.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)  # запускаем через кнопку

    def button_clicked(self):
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label.move(30, 30)
        self.label.setText("TEST")


def window():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


window()
```

Comment: А зачем вы закомментировали строку, привязывающую нажатие на кнопку к выполнению функции?

Comment: Для наглядности. Нужно чтобы лейбл появлялся при нажатии на кнопку. а не сразу

Comment: Сразу скажу - с PyQT ни разу не работал, и могу очень сильно заблуждаться. Но `self.b1.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)` привязывает функцию `self.button_clicked` к сигналу `self.b1.clicked`, чтобы указать ту функцию, которая должна запускаться при нажатии. А вы просто отменяете привязку. Может из за этого нажатие на кнопку не приводит ни к чему?

Comment: я другое не пойму- если функция button_clicked запускается из __init__ лейбл рисуется. Но если убрать строку вызова и задействовать кнопку, то ничего не отрисуется. Хотя сигнал с кнопки проходит...

Comment: @Стас нет, просто если виджет не был создан при инициализации (в конструкторе `__init__`) или не помещается в `layout`, то его необходимо показать, т.е. выполнить `self.label.show()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас есть ДВА варианта:

1. Когда объект `self.label` создается при инициализации

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow


class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()

        self.b1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.b1.setText("click me!")
#        self.button_clicked()  # запускаем напрямую
        self.b1.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)  # запускаем через кнопку
        
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label.move(30, 30)

    def button_clicked(self):
#        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
#        self.label.move(30, 30)
        self.label.setText("TEST")

def window():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window()
```

2. Добавить `self.label.show()`

---

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow


class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()

        self.b1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.b1.setText("click me!")
#        self.button_clicked()  # запускаем напрямую
        self.b1.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)  # запускаем через кнопку

    def button_clicked(self):
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label.move(30, 30)
        self.label.setText("TEST")
        self.label.show()


def window():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window()
```

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо!

Comment: @Дмитрий Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour